# FrameworkEvent ERROR org.eclipse.cdt

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I have added org.eclipse.cdt in my dependencies of my plugin.
When i run the plugin on windows, i get this errror. I get no error while running in Unix.

```
!ENTRY RTI_CustomPlugin 4 0 2016-07-26 11:19:04.269

!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR

!STACK 0

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module:CustomPlugin [605]

  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt; bundle-version="8.8.1"

at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your plugin specifies that you require at least version 8.8.1 of the `org.eclipse.cdt` plugin and that older versions are not acceptable. On your Windows Eclipse an older version of `org.eclipse.cdt` is installed (or it is not installed at all).

You probably need to change your plugin to accept a wider range of versions.

Comment: But im able to add the dependencies by choosing from the list and there the version shown this version only.

Comment: You can change the entry to specify a range of acceptable versions. Select  the entry in the Dependencies list in the MANIFEST.MF editor and click the Properties button.